# Trabalhando com imagens em C#;

Tags: c#, winforms

Então, to trabalhando em um jogo da forca, já está quase pronto.

Falta fazer com que as imagens apareçam via código. E é esse meu problema.

Por exemplo: quero que se o erro for igual a 1, apareça a cabeça e etc. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Podemos. Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua pergunta é muito ampla/aberta. Fica difícil responder de forma assertiva (provavelmente por isso está recebendo votos negativos).

De forma simples, você pode usar o componente `PictureBox` do WinForms.

É bem fácil de usar. Você pode escolher a imagem pelo editor do VisualStudio (janela de propriedades) e setar a propriedade `Visible` para `true` ou `false`.

Eu faria um `PictureBox` para cada parte do corpo e deixaria suas propriedades `Visible` como `false`. Ao longo do jogo, a cada erro, iria "setando" a propriedade `Visibile` para `true`.

---

Alguns links uteis: [PictureBox por DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/picturebox) e [Documentação oficial da classe PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria uma Lista, Pilha ou Fila de imagens em apenas um PictureBox, e quando ocorresse um erro, avança para a próxima imagem.

Fiz um código bem simples, onde o erro acontece no clique do botão:

```
 public partial class FormForca : Form
 {
    List<Image> imagens;
    int erros = 0;
    public FormForca()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imagens = new List<Image>();
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._1);
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._2);
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._3);
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._4);
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._5);
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._6);
        imagens.Add(global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._7);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        erros++;
        pictureBox1.Image = imagens[erros];
        //Se chegou na ultima imagem, volta a primeira.
        if (erros== imagens.Count-1)
        {
            erros = -1;
        }
    }
 }
```

[image: Inicio de jogo]

depois de acontecer os erros:

[image: Fim de jogo]

onde:

```
global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._1
```

é a imagem em branco, 
e:

```
global::LotoFacil.Properties.Resources._7
```

é a imagem final do jogo (boneco enforcado).

Comment: Boa! Existem várias formas de implementar uma solução para esse caso. Mas com "tanto" detalhe que temos na pergunta fica difícil ser assertivo rsrs. Dá inclusive para desenhar no próprio form.. Não precisaria nem de PictureBox :P

Comment: rsrs pois é, mas obrigado. sempre tento ajudar =]

Comment: desenhar na mão uma forca, ta doido, rsrs. Bom é ver que tem sempre alguem negativando minhas postagens, vai saber porque né... rs

Comment: Nossa! Agora que vi que tem um -1.. Doideira...